# Is 32-bit ARM (windows) considered dead/deprecated?

Tags: windows, arm, arm64, windows-rt, windows-11

I was curious about the ARM32 architecture (the 32-bit only version) and it's future: according to the wiki page, the Windows 8 variant Windows RT was ARM32, but it is deprecated now.
Windows 11 seems it will be ARM64-only.
What about devices released in-between?

I could not find any information/statistics related to this.
As far as I know ARM64 can run ARM (32-bit) applications, but one developing a system driver or working low-level has to support both platforms.

For comparison as far as I know, majority of current android phones are 64-bit already and with the 32-bit architecture having the 4GB limitation, logic would dictate, that outside of niche scenarios we should not really see 32bit-only ARM systems.

Anyone has any information regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason for MS to release ARM32 version:

- No chip vendor is launching high end ARM32 chips
- `aarch64` is vastly superior to `aarch32` while not much more expensive for licensees (if at all)
- `aarch64` is NOT backward compatible.

Why would MS want to fragment their Windows eco system more than necessary?

Comment: According to the [wiki on ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#32-bit_operating_systems), windows IoT core runs on 32-bit arm processors. but I was just curious about anything other from MS, that is not completely discontinued on ARM32